# Calculate a probability involving drawings from bivariate normal variables with Xi and Yi i.i.d

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

There's a question which has been troubling me along with my earlier post.

[image: The question]

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure on how to proceed. All I know is that if X~N(mu,sigma^2) then P(X < A) = P(Z< (A-mu)/sigma)

I just need help on starting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You are asked to find $P(2\bar{X}+\bar{Y} > 3)$ where $\bar{X}$ and
$\bar{Y}$ are individually *normal* random variables whose means and variances
you should be able to work out.  More strongly, $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are
*jointly normal* which implies that $2\bar{X}+\bar{Y}$ is also a normal
random variable whose mean and variance you should be able to work out.
You will need to know various results such as
$$\begin{align}
E\left[\sum_i a_iZ_i\right] &= \sum_i a_iE[Z_i]\\
\operatorname{var}\left(\sum_i a_iZ_i\right) &= \sum_i a_i^2\operatorname{var}(Z_i)
+ \sum_i \sum_{j\neq i} a_ia_j \operatorname{cov}(Z_i,Z_j)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Mind if I ask a few more questions? So for E(Zi) if E(Z)=1 can i say E(Zi) = 1?

Comment: My answer was 0.298. Is that right?